# Inherit Grails Domain Class properties to a Base Domain Class

Tags: class, grails, properties, dns

I need to Inherit Grails Domain Class properties to a Base Domain Class.In beforeInsert Event.

Any kind of solution is appreciable.

Comment: I don't understand the question, could you elaborate?

Comment: more elaboration and some sample code would be appreciated.

Comment: I have a Domain class for very table in my application and there is a base Domain class also. And all the Domain classes extend the Base Domain Class. Now I have added a beforeInsert Event in BaseDomain class which gets executed before every save. Here I want the corresponding Domain class Properties in the Base Domain class in the event.

Comment: @Odaiah did you solve this? I have a BaseDomain class having property `createdAt` and method `def beforeInsert() { createdAt = new Date() }` but it's not fired on save.